# Ввод данных в бд laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть 2 базы данных: Users и Comments
В таблицу Users вводятся следующие данные:

```
   protected $fillable = ['name', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

В таблицу Comments вводятся следующие данные:

```
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'text'];
```

Мы имеем данные name и text

Как лучше всего ввести эти данные с помощью laravel?

Comment: Лучше всего вывести их так, как предлагает нам laravel, для чего надо потрудиться открыть прекрасную документацию и найти что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос довольно неточный, но всё равно попробую на него ответить:
Если вы вводите данные через контроллер (т.е. по результату какого-либо HTTP запроса), то используйте
`User::create(['name' => 'Ivan'])` и `Comment::create(['user_id' => '1234', 'text' => 'YourText'])`

- *Поля `created_at` и `updated_at` заполняются автоматически, они появляются от `$table->timestamps()` в файле миграций.*
  *Предполагаю, что у вас есть соответствующие модели `User` и `Comment`*

*Исправление неточностей: `Users` и `Comments` у вас, скорее всего, таблицы, а не базы данных*